# Update sublime editor in cent os 7

Tags: centos-7, sublime-text

Whenever i open sublime text editor it shows please download new version. I downloaded and file which is "sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.tbz". I got this file. Now how to install this updated version on centos 7 ?.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2 (current latest version) from the [official Sublime 3 download webpage](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). The download link for Linux 64-bit build 3211 is [here](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2).
2. Change directories with `cd` to the directory  containing sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2, and extract files from sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2:

   ```
   tar vxjf sublime_text_3_build_3211_x64.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Move the files to the appropriate location in `/opt`.

   ```
   sudo mv /sublime_text_3/ /opt/
   ```
4. Create a symbolic link to use at the command line.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
   ```